# Calculate the total amount

Tags: java, android, toast, onactivityresult

I'm trying to get the total amount and display it as Toast, but I get error as below...I have converted the **String to Long by using Long.parseLong()** but still no luck.

```
Error:(247, 18) error: no suitable method found for makeText(Context,long,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; long cannot be converted to CharSequence)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; possible lossy conversion from long to int)
```

**Code**

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0);
            long a=0,long c1=0;
            long as=0,long as1=0,long as2=0;
            long bs=0,bs1=0,bs2=0;
            if (button == 1) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case 0:
                        String result = data.getStringExtra("text"); //Assume it holds 35
                        String b = data.getStringExtra("a");
                         as=Long.parseLong(result);
                        c.setText("            " + b + "------" + "RM " + result);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        String result1 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                        String b1 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                         as1=Long.parseLong(result1);
                        c.setText("            " + b1 + "------" + "RM " + result1);
                        break;


                    case 2:
                        String result2 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                        String b2 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                         as2=Long.parseLong(result2);
                        c.setText("            " + b2 + "------" + "RM " + result2);
                        break;

                }
            }
            else if(button==2)
            {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case 0:
                        String result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                        String b = data.getStringExtra("a");
                         bs=Long.parseLong(result);
                        d.setText("            " + b + "------" + "RM " + result);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        String result1 = data.getStringExtra("text");
                        String b1 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                         bs1=Long.parseLong(result1);
                        d.setText("            " + b1 + "------" + "RM " + result1);
                        break;


                    case 2:
                        String result2 = data.getStringExtra("text"); //Assume it holds 40
                        String b2 = data.getStringExtra("a");
                         bs2=Long.parseLong(result2);
                        d.setText("            " + b2 + "------" + "RM " + result2);
                        break;

                }

                long x=as+as1+as2;
                long y=bs+bs1+bs2;
                long amount=x+y;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), amount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Do it has another way to write this since I only need to get 1 value from each button. Between, the amount I get is incorrect.

Sorry if it comes across as a silly question....

Comment: the amount I get are incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(amount), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: my answer solves your problem that it cannot be built but not the calculation problem

Comment: Do it has another way to write this since I only need to get 1 value from each button/

Comment: please tell us what you want do calculate (the total amount of WHAT?)

Comment: kindly refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405648/pass-bundle-to-if-statement)